# Access User’s value in model’s file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I would like to ask if is it possible when I have something like this

```
 >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 >>> u = User.objects.get(username='marcel4')
 >>> d = u.employee.department
 >>> print(d)
 >>> 経理部
```

To be able to access that `‘d’` for all Users in `‘models.py’` file. Because I want to be able to do `‘if’` statement depending on the `‘d’`.

Comment: may be `type(d).objects.all()`? but simple way is to do else one import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the `User` objects, like:

```
for u in User.objects.select_related('employee').all():
    d = u.employee.department
    if d == 'some_value':
        # ...
    else:
        # ...
```

That being said, if you want to filter the `User` objects depending on the `department`, you can use a `.filter(..)`, like:

```
for u in User.objects.filter(employee__department='some_value'):
    # ...
    pass
```

Here we will iterate over all `User`s with an `employee` that has a `department` that has `some_value''`. It is more efficient to filter at the database side, not at the Django/Python side.